# Auto refreshing div and new row data with sound alert

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, notifications

I have the following piece of code for auto-refreshing a row. I would like to play a sound alert only if there is an incoming new entry in my database.

The new row updates, the alert message runs, but the notification sound auto replays regardless of whether the database entry is new. I am having difficulty determining:

1. Why the audio replays regardless of whether the database entry is new, and
2. How to make sure the audio message plays based only on some value retrieved from my database (like, timestamp or id, for example)

Below is my code:

**HTML Code:**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    </head>
    <body>

<!-- New Posts -->
    <div id="newposts"></div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

**JavaScript Code:** with findBootstrapEnvironment function

```
<script language="javascript">
    var env = findBootstrapEnvironment();

var audioElement = new Audio();


function playAlert(ignore_checked) {
    if (ignore_checked || (document.getElementById('play_sound') && document.getElementById('play_sound').checked)) {
        if (!document.contains(audioElement)) {
            document.body.appendChild(audioElement);
        }

        if (audioElement.canPlayType("audio/mp3")) {
            audioElement.src = 'notify.mp3';
        } else if (audioElement.canPlayType("audio/wav") || audioElement.canPlayType("audio/x-wav")) {
            audioElement.src = 'notify.wav';
        }

        if (audioElement.currentTime) {
            audioElement.currentTime = 0;
        }

        audioElement.play();
    }
}


    function updateHistory() {
        var datastring = '';
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'GET', url: 'connect.php', data: datastring,
            success: function (server_response) {
                if (server_response != '1') {
                    $('#newposts').html(server_response);
                    if (server_response.length = 0)    return;

                    document.getElementById('updatewarning').innerHTML = '<p><strong>There have been updates to this page.</strong> Please view the updates.</p>';
                    document.getElementById('updatewarning').style.display = 'block';

                    var title = document.title;
                    title = title.replace("UPDATED - ", "");
                    document.title = "UPDATED - " + title;
                    playAlert();
                }
            }
        });

        setTimeout("updateHistory()", 20000);
    }

updateHistory();


    function findBootstrapEnvironment() {
        var envs = ['xs', 'sm', 'md', 'lg'];

        var $el = $('<div>');
        $el.appendTo($('body'));

        for (var i = envs.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            var env = envs[i];

            $el.addClass('hidden-'+env);
            if ($el.is(':hidden')) {
                $el.remove();
                return env;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

**PHP file Code:** I created db with single table (events)

```
<?php
$host="localhost";  //Mysql Database Host Address
$username="root";       //Database Username
$pass="";           //Database Password
$dataname="testdb";     //Database Name

$connect = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $pass)
or die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
mysqli_select_db($connect, $dataname) or die(mysqli_error($con));

$sql = "SELECT * FROM events ORDER BY id DESC";

$result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);

 print "
<div><ul>";

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
            echo "<li><span>" . $row['time'] . "</span></li>"; // Things that you want to fetch
        }

 echo "
</ul></div>";

 ?>
```

Comment: So, you're able to trigger an alert, but not play a sound?

Comment: above code run auto refresh div with sound, but the audio play repeated, I would to play a sound with new entry only depending on the time entry or id for example

Comment: In your `updateHistory()` function, you're not passing a parameter to the `playAlert()` function. I would think that's where you'd want to tell the alert to play (or not) based on your db data - or some logic in your ajax success response.